# A solution to the Four-Color Theorem applied to the map Florida, USA

Tags: graphics, geography, geographics

After struggling for a while with the problem of finding a solution to the Four-Color Theorem applied to the map Florida, USA:

[List of neighbor counties for all counties in a State](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143875/list-of-neighbor-counties-for-all-counties-in-a-state)

[Neighboring counties (within the State of Florida) for every county in the State of Florida](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144187/neighboring-counties-within-the-state-of-florida-for-every-county-in-the-state)

[Sharing a notebook on the four color theorem applied to map of Florida](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2148/four-color-theorem-applied-to-map-of-florida)

[Applying the Four-color Theorem to the map of Florida](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145338/applying-the-four-color-theorem-to-the-map-of-florida)

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146265/four-color-theorem-code-breaks-down-for-two-counties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution is provided at:

http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1112686

Comment: May I include the code from this Notebook in this post?

Comment: Neat! Thanks for sharing